# Saving a Linked List to a file on seperate lines

Tags: java, io, linked-list

I will try to keep this as simple as possible. Basically I have a Linked List of data where every element is on a separate line. However when I try to save it to a file it all just gets linked together in one long String. I need it to save to the file on different lines because I have to keep reading and saving to this file multiple times, and the way I read the file everything has to be on separate lines.
Thanks!

**Code for Saving Linked List to file:**

```
        String file_name = "output.txt";
        try {

                FileWriter fstream = new FileWriter(file_name);
                BufferedWriter out = new BufferedWriter(fstream);

                ListIterator itr = account.listIterator();
                while (itr.hasNext()) {
                    Account element = (Account) itr.next();
                    out.write(element + "\n");
                }

                out.close();
                System.out.println("File created successfully.");

        } catch (Exception e) {
        }
```

**Code for creating Linked List:**

```
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.FileReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.LinkedList;
public class Main extends javax.swing.JFrame implements ActionListener{

public static String readLine(BufferedReader br) throws IOException {
    String rl = br.readLine();
    if (rl.trim().length() > 2){
        return rl;
    }else return readLine(br);
}

public static void main(String[] args) {

    LinkedList<Account> account = new LinkedList<Account>();

    try
    {
        read(account, "output.txt");
    } catch (Exception e)
    {
        System.err.println(e.toString());
    }
        display(account);
    }

    public static void read(LinkedList<Account> account, String inputFileName) throws java.io.IOException
    {
        BufferedReader infile = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(inputFileName));
        while(infile.ready())
        {

            String username = readLine(infile);
            String password = readLine(infile);
            String email = readLine(infile);
            String name = readLine(infile);
            String breed = readLine(infile);
            String gender = readLine(infile);
            String age = readLine(infile);
            String state = readLine(infile);
            String hobby = readLine(infile);

            Account a = new Account(username, password, email, name, breed, gender, age, state, hobby);
            account.add(a);
            a.showList();
        }
        infile.close();
    }

    public static void display(LinkedList<?> c)
    {
        for (Object e : c)
        {
            System.out.println(e);
        }
    }
```

Comment: (Because I like things done right in the first place: You might want to check whether you are printing an end of line character (\n, \r?) within the line text and probably throw an exception. Whitelisting is better than trying to list exceptions. Use `try-finally` (or, more reliably, Java SE 7's `try-()`. You are picking up whatever character encoding happens to be default at the time - better to be explicit with what you want. You are almost always better off with an `ArrayList` than a `LinkedList` - declared variables as `List` and it's easy to swap).

Comment: Thanks for the tips but I have to use LinkedList.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead,

```
out.write(element + "\n");
```

try

```
out.write(element);
out.newLine();
```

Referring to the javadoc of `newLine()` method:

> Write a line separator. The line separator string is defined by the
>   system property line.separator, and is not necessarily a single
>   newline ('\n') character.

So, \n does not seem correct always for new line.

Comment: That works great but it looks like I have another problem. Each account is a separate element so I have to make it so each individual part of the account is an element.

Answer (score 1):

Use `PrintWriter(String fileName).println(...)`. Avoid literal `\n`.

Answer (score 0):

There will be an newline after each `Account` that you write to the file.

```
    Account element = (Account) itr.next();
    out.write(element + "\n");
```

I suspect that the real problem is in the `Account.toString()` method.  Given the way you are reading it, you need to ensure that there is a newline after each field of an account object.

Comment: My toString does that already... it has to be something else but I think you are on the right track. It seems like each account is an element... not each part of the account like I wanted.